# Can't set initial sort order for DataTable programmatically

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I need to set sortBy for DataTable programmatically by bean. DataTable has single sort Mode, static columns, and custom lazy model to sort by custom expressions like = "#{contractor.companyName-MULTY_LANG}".  I tried a lot of ways to do this and only one way works (code below), but works not correctly - Component showed without highlight ordered field. Can anybody answer how the correct way to set sortBy for DataTable programmatically?

```
@PostConstruct
    public void init() {    
        final DataTable d = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(TABLE_COMPONENT_KEY);
        String tableSortByExpression = "#{contractor.companyName-MULTY_LANG}"; // expression from some column
        SortMeta sm1 = new SortMeta();
        for (UIComponent child : d.getChildren()) {
            Column column = (Column)child;
            ValueExpression columnSortByVe = column.getValueExpression("sortBy");
            if (columnSortByVe != null) {
                String columnSortByExpression = columnSortByVe.getExpressionString();
                if (tableSortByExpression != null && tableSortByExpression.equals(columnSortByExpression)) {
                    d.setSortColumn(column);
                    d.setSortOrder("ASCENDING");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'll be appreciate for any help.

---

Primefaces 5.1. Tomcat 7. Mojarra 2.2.8

Comment: Can't you read it from the DB in the preferred default order? It won't highlight the column, but I think it works fine and intuitively

Comment: I'm currently facing the same problem. Did you solve it? (or anyone knows it?)

Comment: Try PF 6.1 first (and you you actually need it be done programmatically? Can't you use xhtml?

Comment: The datatable is being ordered with "sortColumn" and "sortOrder". 

But, as Roman says, it isn't showing the sorted column to the user (in the User Interface). 

I have proved with this but it didn't solved the problem: `UIComponent component = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(TABLE_COMPONENT_KEY:columnId); dataTable.setSortColumn((UIColumn) component);`

Does anyone know how to remark it in the UI?

Comment: @Kukeltje > Can't you use xhtml? => We did a `dataTable.reset();` to clear all field filters and other staff

@Kukeltje > Try PF 6.1 first => We are using this version

Comment: I fail to see where _"We did dataTable.reset(); to clear all field filters and other staff"_ is related to "Can't you use xhtml?" What are you trying to achieve (besides the sorting problem now) that cannot be done using xhtml?

Comment: Indeed, what's wrong with `sortOrder="#{bean.sortOrder}"` in XHTML?

Answer (score 2):

First of all extend org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SortFeature

```
public class CustomSortFeature extends SortFeature {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public void encode(FacesContext context, DataTableRenderer renderer, DataTable table) throws IOException {
        table.setFirst(0);

        if(table.isLazy()) {
            table.loadLazyData();
            singleSort(context, table);
        }
        else {
            if(table.isMultiSort())
                multiSort(context, table);
            else
                singleSort(context, table);

            if(table.isPaginator()) {
                RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();

                if(requestContext != null) {
                    requestContext.addCallbackParam("totalRecords", table.getRowCount());
                }
            }

            //save state
            Object filteredValue = table.getFilteredValue();
            if(!table.isLazy() && table.isFilteringEnabled() && filteredValue != null) {
                table.updateFilteredValue(context, (List) filteredValue);
            }
        }

        renderer.encodeTbody(context, table, true);
    }
}
```

Then try to extend org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer

```
@FacesRenderer(componentFamily = "org.primefaces.component", rendererType = "org.primefaces.component.DataTableRenderer")
public class CustomDataTableRenderer extends DataTableRenderer {
    public List<DataTableFeatureKey> FEATURE = new ArrayList<DataTableFeatureKey>(){/**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    {
        add(DataTableFeatureKey.DRAGGABLE_COLUMNS);
        add(DataTableFeatureKey.FILTER);
        add(DataTableFeatureKey.PAGE);
        add(DataTableFeatureKey.SORT);
        add(DataTableFeatureKey.RESIZABLE_COLUMNS);
        add(DataTableFeatureKey.SELECT);
        add(DataTableFeatureKey.ROW_EDIT);
        add(DataTableFeatureKey.CELL_EDIT);
        add(DataTableFeatureKey.ROW_EXPAND);
        add(DataTableFeatureKey.SCROLL);
        add(DataTableFeatureKey.DRAGGABLE_ROWS);
    }};
    @Override
    protected void preRender(FacesContext context, DataTable table){
        table.setCaseSensitiveSort(false);
        if(table.isLazy()) {
            if(table.isLiveScroll())
                table.loadLazyScrollData(0, table.getScrollRows());
            else
                table.loadLazyData();
        }

        boolean defaultSorted = (table.getValueExpression("sortBy") != null || table.getSortBy() != null);
        if(defaultSorted && !table.isLazy()) {
            table.setDefaultSortByVE(table.getValueExpression("sortBy"));
            table.setDefaultSortOrder(table.getSortOrder());
            table.setDefaultSortFunction(table.getSortFunction());

            CustomSortFeature sortFeature = (CustomSortFeature) table.getFeature(DataTableFeatureKey.SORT);

            if(table.isMultiSort())
                sortFeature.multiSort(context, table);
            else
                sortFeature.singleSort(context, table);  

            table.setRowIndex(-1);
        }

        if(table.isPaginator()) {
            table.calculateFirst();
        }

        Columns dynamicCols = table.getDynamicColumns();
        if(dynamicCols != null) {
            dynamicCols.setRowIndex(-1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException{
        DataTable table = (DataTable) component;
        if(table.shouldEncodeFeature(context)) {
            for(Iterator<DataTableFeatureKey> it = FEATURE.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                DataTableFeature feature = table.getFeature(it.next());

                if(feature.shouldEncode(context, table)) {
                    feature.encode(context, this, table);
                }
            }
        }
        else {  
            preRender(context, table);

            encodeMarkup(context, table);
            encodeScript(context, table);
        }
    }
}
```

Furthermore, add render class to faces-config

```
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
        <render-kit>
            <renderer>
                <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
                <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.DataTableRenderer</renderer-type>
                <renderer-class>com.edtoktay.CustomDataTableRenderer</renderer-class>
            </renderer>
        </render-kit>
</faces-config>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: And for which PF version is this? 5.1?

Comment: The version I was used is PF 5.1 as well. By using this extended classes and also overriding LazyDataModel's load function you can edit and manipulate all the attributes of data table and data model. I used above classes for not only, sorting but also, modify other attributes of datatable programmatically